# Facebook Comments Widget Post Comment Doesnt show image on Wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

How do you set the image, title, and description of Facebook Post that is issued from a comments widget? I assumed it would use what is specified in the og: meta tags. However, even with those set I still see a blank image when I post a comment made in a comments widget.

To clarify, I embed a comments widget in a page. The page has an . When you make a comment in the widget there is a checkbox you can select to "Also post on Facebook". If selected your comment will appear on your wall. When I post the comment I get a blank image, actually it is https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCT_5grD9cot1Jo&w=487&h=255&url=http%3A%2F%2Fe5leader.com%2Fimages%2Fe5_leaders_mark_pierce_paul_koopman.jpg&cfs=1&upscale=1 which turns out to be 1px x 1px   image. The image specified in the meta tag is over 1200x630 so it satisfies Facebook's image best practices.

Seems to me like Facebook has some image cached, but who knows I tried rescraping the page with Facebook's dev tools https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.e5leader.com%2Finputs-outputs-delivery%2F but no dice! The page checks out but still no image.

Any hint would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The image, title, description etc posted form the comments widget to a Facebook feed are defined by the open graph tags on the page the comments widget targets ie the "url to comment on" field on this page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments. It does not use the open graph meta tags defined on the page in which the widget is embeded.